# How do I cast a number to BouncyCastle.BigInteger <--> System.Numerics.BigInteger

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, biginteger, twos-complement, .net-4.5

The slowest part of my code is that I use Bouncy Castle's "BigInteger.Multiply()" method.  To try and speed things up I'm attempting to insert the   code below to see if there is any improvement.

I know that I'm not doing something right, because I'm getting many errors and exceptions when Bouncy Castle see the BigInteger I'm sending to it:

```
         if (this.sign != 1 || val.sign != 1)
        {
            //todo: test encoding, twos compliment
        }
        var tempThis = this.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        Array.Reverse(tempThis);
        System.Numerics.BigInteger aThis = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(tempThis);

        var tempThat = val.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
        Array.Reverse(tempThat);
        System.Numerics.BigInteger bThat = new System.Numerics.BigInteger(tempThat);
        var msResult = System.Numerics.BigInteger.Multiply(aThis, bThat);

        var tmpRet = msResult.ToByteArray();
        Array.Reverse(tmpRet);
        var ret = new BigInteger(tmpRet);
        return ret;
```

This is the original BC function

```
    public BigInteger Multiply(     BigInteger val)
    {

       // THEORY: If I use the native System.Numerics here, then I might get better performance

        if (val == this)
            return Square();

        if ((sign & val.sign) == 0)
            return Zero;

        if (val.QuickPow2Check()) // val is power of two
        {
            BigInteger result = this.ShiftLeft(val.Abs().BitLength - 1);
            return val.sign > 0 ? result : result.Negate();
        }

        if (this.QuickPow2Check()) // this is power of two
        {
            BigInteger result = val.ShiftLeft(this.Abs().BitLength - 1);
            return this.sign > 0 ? result : result.Negate();
        }

        int resLength = magnitude.Length + val.magnitude.Length;
        int[] res = new int[resLength];

        Multiply(res, this.magnitude, val.magnitude);

        int resSign = sign ^ val.sign ^ 1;
        return new BigInteger(resSign, res, true);
    }
```

Comment: The integers you're operating on are not secret?

Comment: @CodesInChaos Does the secrecy/privacy of the number matter when doing BigInteger operations?  Is this something I should be concerned about on a multi-tenant environment / shared system, or just my lone PC.  (or OSX running Parallels + Windows 8?)

Comment: If you use crypto in a network app or you run untrusted applications (even in a VM), you should use a side channel resistant implementation.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Understood. In my situation I'm only verifying signatures, namely the Bitcoin Blockchain in .NET.  If I do use secrets, I would offline a system and vanitygen a key using MSFT Big Integer, then import it into the trusted system.  Is that OK?

Comment: You could re-formulate your question to be more general. All you want to know is how to convert `Org.BouncyCastle.Math.BigInteger` to `CSharp.Numerics.BigInteger`.